# Why is the substitution $((\lambda x \to (\lambda y \to xyz))x)[y/z] $ not allowed?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

$((\lambda x \to (\lambda y \to xyz))x)[y/z] $ means we subsitute every z with y.

Isnt the inner z variable free and thus substitutable ?

Comment: The $z$ is indeed free in this $\lambda$-term, but that does not mean that $y$ is substitutable for $z$ in the term.  Check the definition of substitutability.

Comment: z is a free variable. y is a bound variable.  Replacing z with y changes the meaning of the sentence, at least because the new version has no free variables.  The 'y's are creating a naming conflict, the same name for 2 different things.